# Azure Logic App List Blob what is List_Blob metadata field value

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Hi I am using Azure Logic App to List Blobs and then looping through list and delete blobs that are older than specified date. I have used Azure Portal Logic App Designer to built this.  This is working fine. I would like to know that in below JSON where is metadata value coming from. But in Azure Blob Storage I haven't defined any metadata on container property. Can anyone advise where the metadata is coming from??
I have changed the metadata value and it gives errors.

```
 "List_blobs": {
              "runAfter": {},
              "metadata": {
                "JTJmbmlhbWhwcm9hY3RpdmVpbWFnnnhhhFZXM=": "/containerName"
              },
              "type": "ApiConnection",
              "inputs": {
                "host": {
                  "connection": {
                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                  }
                },
                "method": "get",
                "path": "/datasets/default/foldersV2/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('JTJmbmlhbWhwcm9hY3RpdmVpbWFnnnhhhFZXM='))}",
                "queries": {
                  "nextPageMarker": "",
                  "useFlatListing": false
                }
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metadata in the `List_blobs` is the folder name base64 string, you could check this doc:[Converter functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-content-type#converter-functions). It's used to preserve your some information then use it in other place.

Like in the path property, it uses this metadata and convert it with [encodeUriComponent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#encodeuricomponent) expression because after decode the base64 string its `/` is `%2f`.

So like my folder path is `/test` the metadata is `JTJmdGVzdA==`, and the below is the decode string.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot George for explaining it. In terms of creating Azure logic apps via JSON code ( CI/CD) is it best practice to use metadata property there or there is an alternative way.

Comment: If you want, you could choose to not use the metatdata, you could just define the path like the pic show.https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzaZ0.png

Comment: @Harpreet Singh, and if this could help you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation George. I changed the template with just container name and deployed using AzureDevops. Looks all good.  Thankyou.

Comment: @Harpreet Singh,if this could help you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: I don't see any checkbox to accept this as answer. Can you advise how I do it here? Thanks

Comment: @Harpreet Singh,https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @Harpreet Singh, did you know how to accept answer now? Click on the mark button on the left of the reply to toggle it from greyed out to filled in

Comment: @Harpreet Singh, could you tell me why you don't want to accept my answer?